# First Day of month

Tags: sql

```
select  distinct
  DATEPART("yyyy", datum) AS year
, DATEPART("mm", datum)   AS month 
=
```

Can anybody tell my how i get the first day of the month with it. If I try "Datepart("dd", datum) As day", I get every day instead of only the first day

Comment: What's your DBMS?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That datepart function is product specific.)

Comment: The first day of month is always = 1 , maybe you mean day of week ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: hey this is not how StackOverflow works!  You ask sensible question, people gives answer, and everything is kept for other people's future reference.  You shouldn't mask out your question after you received your answer

Comment: Sorry @AdrianShum, you're right I changed it back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server 2012+ try:

```
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(datum), MONTH(datum), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([datum] date)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (datum)
VALUES
    ('04-06-2018')
;

SELECT distinct DATEPART("yyyy", datum) AS year
  ,DATEPART("mm", datum)   AS month 
  ,DATENAME(dw,CAST(DATEPART("mm", datum) AS VARCHAR) 
   + '/' 
   + CAST('01' AS VARCHAR) 
   + '/' 
   + CAST(DATEPART("yyyy", datum) AS VARCHAR))  AS [First day of month]
FROM table1
order by year, month
```

OutPut

```
year    month   First day of month
2018    4       Sunday
```

**Live Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/69402/4

Answer (score 0):

You can use End of Month function (`EOMONTH()`) with the previous month, and add 1 day.

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2018-06-08'

SELECT
    OriginalDate = @Date,
    EndOfPreviousMonth = EOMONTH(@Date, -1),
    StartOfMonth = DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@Date, -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

First day of month is always 1st.

```
select  distinct
  DATEPART("yyyy", datum) AS year, 
  DATEPART("mm", datum)   AS month, 
  1  AS FirstDayOfMonth
from qdatum
order by year, month
```

(I am clueless on what you are trying to achieve actually)

Comment: @MathijsBiemond Still clueless on what you are trying to achieve... can you be more specific?